# How to use json.load to save info from a txt to a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, dump

I am trying to use json.load on a dictionary; however, I am getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:\Python34\Main.py", line 91, in 
>          main()
>     File "C:\Python34\Main.py", line 87, in main
>        match_histories = json.load("match_histories.txt")
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\json__init__.py", line 265, in load
>      return loads(fp.read(),
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Here is my code (I imported json first):

```
import json
match_histories = {}
match_histories["age"] = 25
json.dump(match_histories, "match_histories.txt")
match_histories = json.load(open("match_histories.txt"))
```

Hmm, now I am getting an error with the dump:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Python34\Main.py", line 91, in 
>      main()
>   File "C:\Python34\Main.py", line 82, in main
>    match_histories=get_match_histories(challenger_Ids)
>   File "C:\Python34\Main.py", line 50, in get_match_histories
>   json.dump(match_histories, "match_histories.txt")
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\json__init__.py", line 179, in dump
>    fp.write(chunk)
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

After attempting what has been suggested, I changed my code to

```
import json
match_histories = {}
match_histories["age"] = 25
with open("match_histories.txt") as match_file:
    match_histories = json.dump(match_histories, "match_histories.txt")
with open("match_histories.txt") as match_file:
    match_histories = json.load(match_file)
```

but I still get the error

> File "C:\Python34\lib\json__init__.py", line 179, in dump
>      fp.write(chunk)
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

(sorry, I am new to python and programming)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

As you can see it tries to call `read()` on the passed object, but you've passed a string object not a file (or any other object that implements `read()`)

`json.load()` wants a file object, not a string of its path, so use `open()` to open the file then pass it, or something like code below:

```
with open('file.json') as json_file:    
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
```

If you're opening the file to be written, you should the `w` mode to `open()` like `open('file.json', 'w')`

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load)

> **json.load(fp, ...)**
>
> Deserialize fp (a .read()-supporting **file-like object** containing a
>   JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion table.

And you have same issue with `json.dump`

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
>
> **json.dump(obj, ...)** Serialize obj as a JSON formatted stream to fp (a
>   .write()-supporting **file-like object**) using this conversion table.

### Example

```
import json
match_histories = {}
match_histories["age"] = 25

print 'Python dict is', match_histories

with open('match.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(match_histories, json_file)

with open('match.json', 'r') as json_file:
    match_histories = json.load(json_file)

print 'Python dict restored from JSON', match_histories
```

### Run it

```
python jsontest.py

Python dict is {'age': 25}
Python dict restored from JSON {u'age': 25}
```

### JSON

```
{"age": 25}
```